# Laravel language handler in templates blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can i use something like {{@something}} and it will run a controller that checks for "something" so i can return it to translteable text?

My current blade template looks like following:

```
@layout("layouts.default")

@section("inner")
  <h1>Velkommen til pornobiksen</h1>

  @foreach($videos as $thumb)
       {{$thumb}}
  @endforeach
 @endsection
```

I mean, how can i change the "Velkommen til pornobiksen" tekst? I know i can make something like

```
View::make("template")->with("h1_text","Velkommen til pornobiksen");
```

But is there not a module/plugin to make it easier? By making like {{@h1_text}} and it will takes from my database or something?

What is the easists way to make this?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `{{ $h1_text }}` to put the variable into your blade template.

```php
@layout("layouts.default")

@section("inner")
  <h1>{{ $h1_text }}</h1>

  @foreach($videos as $thumb)
       {{$thumb}}
  @endforeach
 @endsection
```

**EDIT**

I think I misunderstood you, it seems you are looking for [localization](http://four.laravel.com/docs/)

```php
@layout("layouts.default")

@section("inner")
  <h1>{{ Lang::get('messages.welcome') }}</h1>

  @foreach($videos as $thumb)
       {{$thumb}}
  @endforeach
 @endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

For localization , you can use helper function : `trans`

> home.php

```
return [
    'welcome' => 'Velkommen til pornobiksen'
];
```

> View

```
@layout("layouts.default")

@section("inner")
  <h1>{{trans('home.welcome')}}</h1>

  @foreach($videos as $thumb)
       {{$thumb}}
  @endforeach
 @endsection
```